# bulk collect ...for all usage

Tags: oracle, plsql, bulkinsert

I want to understand the usage and need for bulk collect `forall` statements.

An example mentioned [here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_news/news_plsql_forall_performance_insert.htm)

In most examples in different web pages; authors first fetch data from a table by using bulk collect statements. After that, they are inserting it into target table by using the `forall` statement.

```
DECLARE
TYPE prod_tab IS TABLE OF products%ROWTYPE;
products_tab   prod_tab := prod_tab();
 BEGIN
-- Populate a collection - 100000 rows
SELECT * BULK COLLECT INTO products_tab FROM source_products;

FORALL i in products_tab.first .. products_tab.last
 INSERT INTO target_products VALUES products_tab(i);
```

But I do not understand when to choose this method. I think I can write the code like below:

```
INSERT INTO target_products
SELECT * FROM SOURCE_PRODUCTS;
```

And I think, insert into select statement can work more performance.

So why we need to choose bulk collect `forall` statements? For error logging or any other advantages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can implement your requirement by an `INSERT INTO SELECT` clause, you don't even need to use `forall` and `bulk collect` statements. There is a saying, "***if you can do it in SQL, do it in SQL***".

But in some situations, you may need to process your data row-by-row, which can force you to code a loop. This is actually terrible, it means that your operations within that loop will be executed as single statements over an over. But if you use `forall`, PL/SQL engine will run your loop in a set-based fashion, which would give you a real good performance boost.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the answer to your question is **"when ever you possibly can !".**

The problem with your question is that in the scenario you described you don't even need plsql.

`forall` is for situations you need to perform some operations with plsql on the data you retrieved, before you insert it to the target table. in this case you'l have a large amount of data in a plsql collection that you would want to bulk insert into the target table. this is what `forall` is for and it's much more efficient then insert in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice article about the use of bulk collect and forall:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-sep/o52plsql-1709862.html

Comment: Do you have any idea about data pump?