# How to Use Table API of Oracle for inserting data from one table to another using PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I'm pretty new to Oracle. I need to know how to use procedural language to insert data from one table to another, Using **Cursor and Table API**. I have searched a lot and have come here.
For example lets take a scenario of employees, we need to fetch all the details of the employees from the employees table and insert it into a table named "employees_backup".
I need to know how it can be implemented using **Cursor,Table API** with best programming practice. 
I have done the following. **but i havent done cursor implementation and Table API implementation.** So guide me how to do it.

Package Specification:

```
 create or replace employee_package 
 AS
 procedure getemployees(department_id IN NUMBER);
```

I'm passing department_id to get only the specific department staffs.

Package Body:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE
 PACKAGE BODY employee_package AS
 PROCEDURE getemployees(department_id IN NUMBER) AS
 BEGIN
 INSERT INTO employees_backup select * from employees WHERE 
 department_id = department_id;
 END employee_package;
```

This is done without Using Table API. I need to know how to implement it using Table API. If cursor can be used, Including Cursor implementation as well. Hope i have explained the question well enough to not get flagged.

Comment: In databases, "best programming practice" is to use plain SQL

Comment: It's obviously your decision, but it's a little bit like asking "I have a simple and efficient solution, can someone show me the slow and painful one" ;-)

Comment: I cited a simple example to ask how this can be done through Table API and Cursor. So that, there isn't a complex answer coming from experts @wolφi

Comment: No, your example is absolutely fine and well explained!

Comment: So can you tell me how this can be achieved through TAPI and cursor if applicable. @wolφi

Comment: Cursor will most probably be way slower than pure INSERT. Bulk might help, though.

Comment: Do you have a reference for or a link to Table API?

Comment: No i don't. @wolφi

Comment: Mmm, then I'm stuck there. "Table API" doesn't ring a bell...

Comment: @KaushikNayak can you suggest an usage for Table API?

Answer (score 0):

You could code along the following lines:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE employee_package AS
  PROCEDURE getemployees(p_department_id IN NUMBER);
  PROCEDURE getmanyemployees(p_department_id IN NUMBER);
  PROCEDURE getfastemployees(p_department_id IN NUMBER);
END employee_package;
/
```

This impliments 3 procedures to compare the (prefered) plain SQL and the cursor bulk collect method.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY employee_package AS

  PROCEDURE getfastemployees(p_department_id IN NUMBER) AS
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO backup_employees e
    SELECT * FROM employees WHERE department_id = p_department_id;
  END getfastemployees;

  PROCEDURE getemployees(p_department_id IN NUMBER) AS
    TYPE emp_type IS TABLE OF employees%ROWTYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
    emp_array emp_type;
  BEGIN
    SELECT * 
      BULK COLLECT INTO emp_array
      FROM employees
     WHERE department_id = p_department_id;

    FORALL i IN 1 .. emp_array.COUNT
      INSERT INTO backup_employees VALUES emp_array(i);          
  END getemployees;

  PROCEDURE getmanyemployees(p_department_id IN NUMBER) AS

    CURSOR cur (c_department_id NUMBER) IS 
    SELECT * 
      FROM employees 
     WHERE department_id = c_department_id;

    TYPE emp_type IS TABLE OF cur%ROWTYPE;
    emp_array emp_type;
  BEGIN
    OPEN cur(p_department_id);
    LOOP
      FETCH cur BULK COLLECT INTO emp_array LIMIT 1000; 

      FORALL i IN 1..emp_array.COUNT
        INSERT INTO backup_employees VALUES emp_array(i);

      EXIT WHEN cur%NOTFOUND;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cur;
    COMMIT;
  END getmanyemployees;

END employee_package;
/
```

For 100.000 employees, getfastemployees(50) takes 0.88s, getmanyemployees 1.54, and getemployees 9.5s. Interestingly, for 2.7 million employees, getfastemployees and getmanyemployees are still in the same region.

See also [bulk collect ...for all usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17087020/bulk-collect-for-all-usage) etc.

Comment: can you also specify how to insert using TAPI? ill approve your answer after that, since no one else is wise enough to answer. @wolφi